# SwiftUI: TabView shows in Preview but now showing on simulated devices

Tags: swiftui

I am using `TabView` in my SwiftUI app.  I used the side Preview as I was building it.  The bottom tab shows on all device types in the Preview section but when I build it to either a real device or simulate device, the TabView doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previews are for each individual view. They don't represent the whole app.

You'll need to set it as the root view inside `YourAppName_App.swift`.

```
@main
struct YourAppNameApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            YourTabBarView() /// replace with the name of your tab bar view
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh I see that file now.  I'll make the appropriate changes.  Thank you!